# How to properly pass table data through Javascript function

Tags: javascript, csv, handsontable

I am using django to set up a basic web app. I have a Handsontable, which using a form, allows users to update the table, press a SAVE button and save the changes to a csv file. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to pass the data properly.

My approach is that the afterChange function should, when the table is updated, pass the data into the table_data_dump div in order for this to be used in python code pressing the SAVE button executes.

However it doesnt seem to be doing this, and I can't figure out the proper usage of the data variable. I'm new to JS so getting confused pretty easily.

Full JS below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $.ajaxSetup ({
            // Disable caching of AJAX responses
            cache: false
        });

        var data = [['', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', ''],
                    ['', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', ''],
                    ['', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '']];

        var dataArray = {};

            dataArray['bnb'] = '/static/data/oim-oimom/lookup_bnb.csv'

            dataArray['testsplit'] = '/static/data/oim-oimom/lookup_testsplit.csv'

            dataArray['test two'] = '/static/data/oim-oimom/lookup_test-two.csv'


        var afterChange = function() {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            document.getElementById('table_data_dump').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data)
        };

        var createTable = function(data) {

            var container = document.getElementById('lookup');
            var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
                data: data,
                afterChange: afterChange,
                minSpareRows: 1,
                rowHeaders: true,
                colHeaders: ['col1','col2','col3', 'Assignment'],
                columns: [
                    {readOnly: true},
                    {readOnly: true},
                    {readOnly: true},
                    {}
                ],
                colWidths: [335, 335, 335, 335]
                })};

        createTable(data);

        var SelectBoxChange = function() {
            var e = document.getElementById("split_name_select");
            var split_select = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            $.get(dataArray[split_select], function(data) {
                document.getElementById('lookup').innerHTML='';
                data = $.csv.toArrays(data);
                createTable(data);

            });

        };

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured this out, so just in case it is of use to anyone else...

I should have been using the `getData()` method of the Handsontable here, however it was giving me an undefined error for `hot.getData()` because of the scope of my variables. I changed these to global and then could access the data.

Further to this `afterChange` needs to be set using the `updateSettings()` method after the table is created. This is to allow the container to be defined, to then be referenced in the `afterChange` function before being assigned.

Thanks